# Query table columns from another table using the foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get customer email and phonenumber in `orders` table when I have the order id.

The structure of the schema is below with customer id in orders table:

**orders**

```
id
date
item
refid
customerFk
```

**customers**

```
id
name
email
phonenumber
```

when I try to retrieve the customers phonenumber or email table from the `order` refId in SQL Server using

```
select 
from order a 
where a.custtomerFK.email
```

I get this error

> Cannot call method on bigints

Please assist with the proper query.

Comment: Please research [joins](http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-joins/)

Comment: Given the comments made below the suggested answers, this question would be improved by the addition of some sample data and the expected result data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper syntax is:

```sql
    SELECT o.date, o.item, o.refid c.Name, c.email, c.phonenumber
    FROM orders o
    LEFT JOIN customers c ON o.customerFk = c.id
    ORDER BY o.date, o.item, c.name
```

Comment: what about where customerfk is not equal to c.id

Comment: @Blaze - That would be a "normal" situation. You can have many customers that do not have current orders. No reason to report them.

Comment: but I want it for some reasons

Comment: @Blaze then replace `LEFT JOIN` with `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: @Blaze, of course a "better" solution would be a separate queries for orders without customers (see my comment above) and customers without orders. Here's a good reference for the types of SQL `JOINs`: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use this if you have customers for each order

```
SELECT orders.date, orders.item, orders.refid 
    , customers.Name, customers.email, customers.phonenumber
FROM orders
INNER JOIN customers ON orders.customerFk = customers.id
```

Comment: The reason I typically avoid `INNER JOIN` even when one would expect to have a relationship is to spot the errors that can be hidden if a `LEFT JOIN` isn't used. That is, in this example, if an application somehow creates an order without a customer record (there might be a "reason" someone thinks it's a good idea at the time) then that record disappears rather than being seen with a `NULL` customer.

Comment: @daShier that is why i said "if you have customers for each order" in the begining

Comment: I did see your qualifier. That's why I said "even when one would expect to have a relationship". I could see a case for `INNER JOIN` for an order processing query where you don't want a "bad record" shown that can't be processed because there's no customer. But in such a case, I would set up an "error report" that shows the `WHERE IS NULL customers.id` lost records. The combination of both would be robust, but most likely beyond the scope of the application of the OP here. ;)

Comment: @daShier . . . It is entirely reasonable that a column called `customerFK` would have a valid `customer.id` value.  That is how foreign keys work.  Unnecessary use of `left join` can slow down queries in some situations.